# Declarative representation of the x86 instruction set

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm writing an x86 backend for a compiler and am finding it really tedious encoding the machine code for each assembly instruction I need and I'm obviously reinventing the wheel. Is there a declarative representation of this instruction set anywhere, e.g. an XML file mapping instruction operations and operands to bytes?

Comment: Can't you just use an x86 assembler? MASM, TASM - google them.

Comment: One of these? http://ref.x86asm.net/

Comment: Why not look at how llvm x86 backend works? it's open source and fairly clear (although not very simple..)

Comment: Alternatively, just use LLVM IR. No instruction encoding - or even instruction *selection* - to worry about, slightly more portable, free optimizations, more reliable codegen.

Comment: @delnan - IR is a perfect representation for code as long as you don't actually want to run it on an x86 machine :)

Comment: @Leeor You can compile it to x86 assembly, to x86 machine code (in various object code formats), you can interpret it, you can JIT compile it (using either the old JIT or the MC JIT) to x86 machine code, you can compile it to JavaScript using Emscripten and run it in a JS engine running on a x86 machine, you can compile it to ARM or MIPS or x64 or one of several other architectures and run it in a VM hosted by a x86 machine. If the x86 machine has a GPU you might even be able to compile it into a GPU program and run it on the GPU ;-)

Comment: @delnan, I meant you can't run the IR directly (not unless you want the machine to go "lol, wtf?"), compiling it means that you need an x86 backend, which I believe is exactly what he's asking for. The rest of the tricks are fine as well (except for the GPU, that's cheating), but I think it's a little overkill for a question about compilers :)

Comment: @Leeor The point is that you use *LLVM's x86 backend(s)* which is probably superior to anything OP creates in every aspect (except, of course, learning experience for OP).

Comment: @Harold: Thanks for the link. If you make it an answer I'll upvote and choose.

Comment: Everyone else: I've already used LLVM and the result was the HLVM project (http://www.ffconsultancy.com/ocaml/hlvm/) which is great but I'd like the learning experience of writing my own code gen and I'd like to improve upon LLVM in terms of GC support and JIT compilation performance.

Comment: @delnan, that's why I suggested LLVM backend. I thought you meant that he should leave the backend and focus on IR only for some reason. Nevermind then.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend using [DynASM](http://luajit.org/dynasm.html) for this.  It's not a declarative description, but it gives you absolute control over what instructions are emitted, and it's much easier to use than a declarative description would be.  It's the ideal way of writing a platform-specific codegen IMO.

It is also very small and unimposing: the runtime is completely contained within a few hundred lines of `.h` files.

See my [DynASM tutorial](http://blog.reverberate.org/2012/12/hello-jit-world-joy-of-simple-jits.html) for an example of writing a very simple codegen with DynASM.

Even if you're not convinced about DynASM, you'll find in the DynASM codebase [a pretty concise declarative description of x86 instructions](http://repo.or.cz/w/luajit-2.0.git/blob/8944e27762712679e50962598ed1be8dc1fbe7be:/dynasm/dasm_x86.lua#l830), which you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming below that you don't want to depend on something huge like LLVM at runtime.

The reason I have researched this question is that I want to add a machine code emitter to a [self-hosting Lisp](https://github.com/attila-lendvai/maru) whose size is in the ballpark of 2000-3000 LoC. Settling with the current LLVM dependency, or the Gnu assembler dependency, would invalidate the very ideal behind this project: self-host from as little code as feasible.

Here's what I have found for now:

### There's also LLVM's TableGen

It's not trivial, and to generate your own code from its declarative description you'll need to write C++ code (unless you're ready to parse and process its format yourself). It's comprehensive, but not the simplest.

https://llvm.org/docs/TableGen/index.html

[lib/Target/X86/X86InstrInfo.td](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/lib/Target/X86/X86InstrInfo.td)

```
llvm-tblgen-10 --help
```

### There's a simpler one in the Previous NEXT emulator

This is basically a web of `#define` C macros that can be processed relatively simply ([see a Lisp example](https://github.com/attila-lendvai/maru/blob/maru.8/source/assembler/gen-asm-x86.l)).

Here are the copies/versions that I have found online:

https://github.com/cebix/macemu/blob/master/BasiliskII/src/uae_cpu/compiler/codegen_x86.h

https://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/previous/newsrc/src/cpu/jit/codegen_x86.h.html

http://previous.unixdude.net/

https://github.com/probonopd/previous/blob/master/src/cpu/jit/codegen_x86.h